# Regex substitution using a list element with just 3 digits index doesn't work as I expected

Tags: regex, perl

Today I encountered [a twitter post](https://twitter.com/shinh/status/663715003690692608) told me another mysterious Perl behaviour.  Could someone please tell me what's wrong with the 3rd statement in following script?  I'm looking for relevant part of document in perldoc.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$x[1]    = "foo"; $_ = "foo"; s/$x[1]/bar/;    print "$_\n";
$x[10]   = "foo"; $_ = "foo"; s/$x[10]/bar/;   print "$_\n";
$x[100]  = "foo"; $_ = "foo"; s/$x[100]/bar/;  print "$_\n";
$x[1000] = "foo"; $_ = "foo"; s/$x[1000]/bar/; print "$_\n";

__END__
bar
bar
foo
bar
```

It seems like perl interpreter tends to separate `$x` from `[100]`.

```
$x[100] = 'foo';
$_ = 'foo';
s/${x}[100]/bar/;
print "$_\n";
```

---

### Edit

Thank you all.  I found a documentation in the Camel Book, and it recommends
exact same as @fred-gannet said.  The factors of the heuristic are the number
of character occurrences and the pruning strategy in the bracket.

https://books.google.com/books?id=xx5JBSqcQzIC&lpg=PR1&pg=PA65#v=onepage&q&f=false

> Within search patterns, which also undergo double-quotish interpolation,
>   there is an unfortunate ambiguity: is `/$foo[bar]/` to be interpolated as
>   `/${foo}[bar]/` (where [bar] is character class for the regular expression)
>   or as `/${foo[bar]}/` (where [bar] is the subscript to array @foo)?  If
>   `@foo` doesn't otherwise exists, it's obviously a character class.  If `@foo`
>   exists, Perl takes a good guess about [bar], and is almost always right.†  If
>   it does guess wrong, or if you're just plain paranoid, you can force the
>   correct interpolation with braces as shown earlier.  Even if you're merely
>   prudent, it's probably not a bad idea.

https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=133027#txn-1542459

> The code is in S_intuit_more().

https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/823ba440369100de3f2693420a3887a645a57d28/toke.c#L4207-L4217

```
if (*s == '$')
    weight -= 3;
else if (isDIGIT(*s)) {
    if (s[1] != ']') {
    if (isDIGIT(s[1]) && s[2] == ']')
        weight -= 10;
    }
    else
    weight -= 100;
}
Zero(seen,256,char);
```

And there is an explanation of the logic, in Japanese. (surprisingly!)

https://8-p.info/perl-interpolation/

Comment: Randomly I have tried, `111` `222` `333` `444` ... `999`  is considering for substitution but rest of all not considering for substitution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently perl is getting confused between an array index and regular expression character sets (e.g. `/[a-z]/`). The behaviour is not consistent. The indexes of 100 to 998 seems to be effected by this. Please report the bug using the script [`perlbug`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlbug.html).

Comment: Not for all index `111` `222` `333` ..`999` for those it will give the result

Comment: FYI I've done the perlbug dance: https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=133027

Answer (score 2):

Expression evaluates consistently when bracketed as

```
s/${x[100]}/bar/;
```

Inconsistency of interpretation when index is 100..998 seems bug like.